# TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Tags: nodejs, express, socket.io, server

estoy haciendo un chat con NodeJS, SocketIO y Express, pero tengo este problema cuando quiero iniciar el servidor, por favor ayuda:

```
require('./sockets')(socketio);
                    ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\miri pc\Documents\chatjavascript\src\index.js:11:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Este es el código:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app  = express();

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io')(server);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

require('./sockets')(socketio);

//archivos estáticos
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('conectado en el puerto', app.get('port'));
})
```

Mi versión de NodeJS es la v17.9.0, mi versión de Socket.IO es la 4.5.0 y mi versión de Express es la 4.18.1.

Comment: Puedes subir agregar el código del archivo `sockets`?

Comment: @Fedex7501 es un paquete [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

Comment: Ese seria `require('socket.io')`. Yo me refiero al `require('./sockets')` que te está dando el error.

Comment: Misma pregunta en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063986/can-you-help-me-with-nodejs-and-socketio#comment127333835_72063986